# Biblatex with multiple bibliographies on documentclass book

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing a book-like document, for which I need to use the LaTeX documentclass book (I'm using chapters, etc.). At the end of the document I want a unique bibliography, broken in several themes, just like this:

[image: Biblography example]

I've produced the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Biblio-test.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Notes for logic and the theory of computation.


\nocite{Ben12}\nocite{GJ79}\nocite{Gor16}\nocite{HMU06}
\nocite{HR04}\nocite{Sip12}

\section*{Bibliography}

\vspace{5mm}

\printbibliography[keyword=Logic, title={\normalsize\normalfont Logic:}] 
\printbibliography[keyword=Computation,
     title={\normalsize\normalfont Theory of Computation:}]

\end{document}
```

which does exactly what I want when the documentclass is article. The entries of the .bib file are the following:

```
@BOOK{Ben12,
AUTHOR="M. Ben-Ari",
TITLE="Mathematical Logic for Computer Science",
PUBLISHER="Springer",
EDITION="3rd edition",
keywords="Logic",
YEAR={2012}                                 }

@BOOK{GJ79,
AUTHOR="M. R. Garey and D. S. Johnson",
TITLE="Computers and Intractability: a Guide to the Theory of {NP}-Completeness",
PUBLISHER="W. H. Freeman \& Co.",
keywords="Computation",
YEAR={1979}                                 }

@BOOK{Gor16,
AUTHOR="V. Goranko",
TITLE="Logic as a Tool: A Guide to Formal Logical Reasoning",
PUBLISHER="Wiley",
keywords="Logic",
YEAR={2016}                                 }

@BOOK{HMU06,
AUTHOR="J. E. Hopcroft and R. Motwani and J. D. Ullman",
TITLE="Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation",
PUBLISHER="Addison-Wesley",
EDITION="3rd edition",
keywords="Computation",
YEAR={2006}                                 }

@BOOK{HR04,
    AUTHOR="M. Huth and M. Ryan",
    TITLE="Logic in Computer Science: Modelling and Reasoning about Systems",
    PUBLISHER="Cambridge University Press",
    EDITION="2nd edition",
    keywords="Logic",
    YEAR={2004}                                 }

@BOOK{Sip12,
    AUTHOR="M. Sipser",
    TITLE="Introduction to the Theory of Computation",
    PUBLISHER="Cengage Learning",
    keywords="Computation",
    EDITION="3rd edition",
    YEAR={2012}                                 }
```

However, as soon as I change the documentclass to book and the \section commands to \chapter, I run into trouble: the header "Bibliography" appears alone in a page, followed by an empty page, followed by a page only with the "Logic" entries, then followed by another empty page, followed by a page only with the "Theory of Computation" entries.

How can I manage to get in the documentclass book a similar formatting for the bibliography as the one I get when the documentclass is article?

Comment: It would be slightly easier to reproduce what you are seeing if you could include all necessary `.bib` entries from the example (maybe reduce the number to two or four, to keep things shorter)... Right now I have to make up additional entries myself to get things working.

Comment: I've just included all the .bib entries I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put formatting commands into the `title` key. It should only contain the title text. Any additional formatting should be performed via bibliography headings. You can use a particluar heading style with the `heading` option and define a new one with `\defbibheading`.

For your set-up something like

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{aristotle:anima,aristotle:physics,nussbaum}

\printbibheading
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, keyword=primary, title={Logic}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, keyword=secondary,  title={Theory of Computation}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Split bibliography with subheadings (\section*)]

seems natural, where `subbibliography` is a predefined heading that uses a sectioning command one level below the normal `bibliography` heading (for the `book` class `bibliography` uses `\chapter*` and `subbibliography` uses `\section*`).

You can also roll your own heading style, for example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\defbibheading{topicbib}{\paragraph{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{aristotle:anima,aristotle:physics,nussbaum}

\printbibheading
\printbibliography[heading=topicbib, keyword=primary, title={Logic}]
\printbibliography[heading=topicbib, keyword=secondary,  title={Theory of Computation}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Split bibliography with subheadings (\paragraph)]